# How can I add image to facebook login button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook-login

I am using facebook login on my site. Everything is working using the facebook button. I would like to change the graphic image to be my own image. How can I change this?

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="fb-login-button cs" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge"></div>
```

How can I add my own CSS so I can able to change the picture itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it http://jsfiddle.net/Mohamed_nabil/2efxE/
Just change the background with yours.

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe{
    opacity: 0;
}
.fb_iframe_widget{
    background: #00D6FF;/*Change this with your custom background*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fb-button {
background-image: url('...');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Black-Hole I have already applied this but its not working.

Comment: this won't over-ride the style you need !important

Comment: try .fb-button!important  {
background-image: url('...');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: just like saj said you can override css classes using !imoportant :

.fb-button { background:url('...') no-repeat !important }

Comment: Thanks @saj, I did but still it is not working showing default image.

Comment: @RaghavSingh can you give us a link of your page?

Comment: Hmmm, ok easier than that is to set in a image in a parent div then load the button inside it. don't you think @RaghavSingh ?

Comment: @Black-Hole, Its not live yet. I did as you said Saj, but now login button is showing outside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `background-image` pointing to a `url()` where your image file is. Adjust its size via `background-size`. You could add this to an existing class (augmenting that class), or you could create a new class and add the new class to the existing HTML element.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/gazuf/2/edit

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-login-button cs" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.fb-login-button {
  width: 128px; /* Width & height added for demo only. */
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/256/80);
  background-size: 128px 40px;
}
```

DOCS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size